# Indexing in two dimensional PyTorch Tensor using another Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose that tensor A is defined as:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I'm trying to extract a flat array out of this matrix by using another tensor as indices. For example, if the second tensor is defined as:

```
0
1
2
3
```

I want the result of the indexing to be 1-D tensor with the contents:

```
1
6
11
16
```

It doesn't seem to behave like NumPy; I've tried `A[:, B]` but it just throws an error for not being able to allocate an insane amount of memory and I've no idea why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st Approach: using `torch.gather`**

```
torch.gather(A, 1, B.unsqueeze_(dim=1))
```

if you want one-dimensional vector, you can add squeeze to the end:

```
torch.gather(A, 1, B.unsqueeze_(dim=1)).squeeze_()
```

**2nd Approach: using list comprehensions**

You can use list comprehensions to select the items at specific indexes, then they can be concatenated using the `torch.stack`. An importat point here is that you should not use `torch.tensor` to create a new tensor from a list, if you do, you will break the chain (you cannot calculate gradient through that node):

```
torch.stack([A[i, B[i]] for i in range(A.size()[0])])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your Tensor to a NumPy array. If you are using Cuda, don't forget to pass it to cpu. If don't, there is no need to pass it to cpu. Example code is below:

```
val.data.cpu().numpy()[:,B]
```

Let me know if it resolves your issue

Comment: Will PyTorch still be able to calculate the gradient? I'm using this piece of code in the loss function, and I was worried if I use NumPy it won't be able to calculate the gradient properly.

Comment: After you gather the array, you can create new tensor from that and you will be able to calculate the gradient. It would be quite complicated but I believe that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch implements torch.take which is equivalent to [numpy.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but `torch.take` treats the input as if it's 1-dimensional. Dealing with that will require shifting the indices, which is not an option. The arrays I'm dealing are really large and this isn't an option.